# Moment JS - isAfter returning .isAfter is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a problem inside my React component. I am trying to only show the data which is upcoming in the future or today only. But i get this error:

**.isAfter is not a function** when i use the format.

Without the format it works, but i get wrong data back.

In short: I want to display upcoming events only.

my code:

```
showData = () => {
    const { checks } = this.props;

    return (
        this.state.opendagen.length > 0 &&
        this.state.opendagen.map((value, index) => {
            const { opendag_data: datum } = value;
            const date = Moment(datum, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD/M/YYYY');
            const now = Moment().format('DD/M/YYYY');

            console.log('vandaag:', now, 'data:', date);

            const concatData = [
                ...(value.opendag_department + ' - '),
                ...(value.opendag_data + ' - '),
                ...value.opendag_link,
            ];

            return date.isAfter(now) ? (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td data-th="Datum">{value.opendag_data}</td>
                    <td data-th="Opleiding">
                        <strong>{value.opendag_department}</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Link">
                        <a
                            target="_blank"
                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            href={value.opendag_link}>
                            bekijk website
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Select">
                        <CheckBox
                            thisClassName="data__checkbox checkbox__input"
                            value={concatData.join('')}
                            id={'string_' + index}
                            onChange={checks}
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ) : null;
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: When you call `format` you turn the moment into a string. Try to remove `.format('DD/M/YYYY')` and see if that works instead.

Comment: Use `Moment(date, 'DD/M/YYYY').isAfter(now)` to convert the sting to moment object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `date` variable is not a `moment` object, as you have used the `format` here

```
const date = Moment(datum, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD/M/YYYY');
```

format method on moment object returns a formatted string, so your `date` variable is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

`Moment().format()` will return a string. A string will not respond to `isAfter()`.

You need to either assign your formatted date to another variable, or just format it at the point you wish to display it:

```
const date = Moment(datum, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
const now = Moment();

return date.isAfter(now) ? ( // <-- this now works 
  ...
```